# Poor decision of IEnumerable of IEnumerable of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, iterator

I wish to improve a class design that causes me readability and performance problems as the code grows.

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string SalesAmountInUSD { get; }
    public IEnumerable<CurrencyWeight> weightOfEachCurrenciesForProductCategory { get; }
}

public class CurrencyWeight
{
    public string Currency{ get; }
    public double Weight { get; }
    public IEnumerable<RetailerWeight> weightOfEachRetailerInEachCurrencyForAProduct { get; }
}

public class RetailerWeight
{
    public string Retailer { get; }
    public double Weight { get; }   
}
```

First problem that occurs to me is readability, as it's not very clear what the `IEnumerable` represents.

`CurrencyWeight` is supposed to be the proportion of each currency in the total sales amount (which is in US dollar because it is easier to manipulate everything in the same currency and apply changerate as late as possible). `RetailerWeight` is the proportion of the sales revenue from a retailer for each currency for a product category.

`ProductCategory` is built from database, here is a Dto class :

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public double SaleAmount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double SaleAmountUSD { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public string Retailer { get; set; }
}
```

My second problem is usage, because I will end up with an `IEnumerable<ProductCategory>` containing an `IEnumerable<CurrencyWeight>` containing `IEnumerable<RetailerWeight>`, and if, for example, I need to apply a change rate and `CurrencyWeight` and `RetailerWeight` on `ProductCategory.SalesAmountInUSD`, i'll have a triple `foreach` loop that will probably be very poorly performant.

At first, I tried to create dictionnaries to uncouple everything :

```
public class AggregationKey
{
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyWeightV2
{
    public string Currency{ get; }
    public double Weight { get; }  
}

Dictionnary<AggregationKey, IEnumerable<CurrencyWeightV2>> currencyWeightRepository;
```

And in the same fashion :

```
public class SubAggregationKey
{
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; }
    public string Currency { get; }
    public string Retailer { get; }
    public AggregationKey getAggregationKey => new AggregationKey(ProductCategoryName, Currency);
}

public class SubContractorWeightV2
{
    public string Retailer{ get; }
    public double Weight { get; }  
}

Dictionnary<SubAggregationKey, IEnumerable<SubContractorWeightV2>> subContractorWeightRepository;
```

However I realized the number of loops needed to apply a change rate and `CurrencyWeight` and `RetailerWeight` on `ProductCategory.SalesAmountInUSD` (example i used above) didn't change, not mentionning the cost of grouping by the `ProductDto` to fill those dictionnaries. I didn't solve my problem, I merely displaced it, isn't it ?

I am also not too sure about the clarity of what `subContractorWeightRepository` represents. While I wish to uncouple the `IEnumerable<CurrencyWeight>` and  `IEnumerable<RetailerWeight>`, they have little meaning on their own, don't they ?

Thanks for taking the time to read and answer, tell me if I forgot an important information.

(I didn't include any constructor to keep example code small but they are all just passing parameters to initialize properties, as you would expect. Nothing fancy here).

Comment: Avoid [cross-posting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370854/improve-a-design-with-ienumerable-of-ienumerable-of-ienumerable) please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP posted incomplete code by removing some parts like constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Naming

```
public class CurrencyWeight
{
    public IEnumerable<RetailerWeight> weightOfEachRetailerInEachCurrencyForAProduct { get; }
}
```

The approach to naming you've used here is not correct. This property should not be referring to a product.

A relationship is between **two** entities. But yours refers to three entities:

> [weightOfEachRetailer] InEach [Currency] ForA [Product]

**[Product]** has nothing to do with this relationship. Whether or not the `CurrencyWeight` has a `ProductCategory`or not does not matter to the relationship between `RetailerWeight` and `CurrencyWeight`. This is violating the principle of encapsulation, you're adding (naming) references that are not necessary.

Additionally, **[Currency]** doesn't need to be referenced here either. This property is part of the `CurrencyWeight` class, which already means that it's "in a Currency[Weight]".

A simpler example of this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string NameOfEmployee;
}
```

`NameOfEmployee` is redundant. `Name` suffices, as it's already a property of the `Employee` class.

This is a case of [Smurf Naming Convention](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/):

> When almost every class has the same prefix. I.e., when a user clicks on the button, a **Smurf**AccountView passes a **Smurf**AccountDTO to the **Smurf**AccountController. The **Smurf**ID is used to fetch a **Smurf**OrderHistory which is passed to the **Smurf**HistoryMatch before forwarding to either **Smurf**HistoryReviewView or **Smurf**HistoryReportingView. If a **Smurf**ErrorEvent occurs it is logged by **Smurf**ErrorLogger to ${app}/**smurf**/log/**smurf**/**smurf**log.log

In other words, the following name is sufficiently descriptive:

```
public class CurrencyWeight
{
    public IEnumerable<RetailerWeight> RetailerWeights { get; }
}
```

The rest of the information that you attempted to provide in the name of the property should be apparent from the relationship between the classes.

---

### Iterating over collections

> My second problem is usage, because I will end up with an IEnumerable containing an IEnumerable containing IEnumerable

This is not a problematic situation in and of itself. If you intentionally loaded this entity graph, there is nothing wrong with that.

For example, if I want to display a list of cities, their province, and their country, I'm going to have an `IEnumerable<Country>` where every `Country` has an `IEnumerable<Province>` where every `Province` has an `IEnumerably<City>`.

You don't **always** need to load all this data, e.g. if you're only interested in a list of countries, all you need is an `IEnumerable<Country>` where every `Country` has an `IEnumerable<Province>` property **which is null**.

> and if, for example, I need to apply a change rate and CurrencyWeight and RetailerWeight on ProductCategory.SalesAmountInUSD,

If you need to set a value in many objects; you're obviously going to need to have the needed objects in memory. That's pretty much unavoidable.

> i'll have a triple foreach loop that will probably be very poorly performant.

Triple foreaches are not necessarily bad, **when they are warranted**. Sometimes, you can simplify them. Returning to the Country-Province-City example:

```
foreach(var country in myCountryList)
    foreach(var province in country.Provinces)
        foreach(var city in province.Cities)
        {
            city.Name = "Foo";
        }
```

This can be simplified to:

```
foreach(var city in myCountryList.SelectMany(c => c.Provinces).SelectMany(p => p.Cities))
{
     city.Name = "Foo";
}
```

However, if you need to set a property on **every** level, then you can't avoid the triple foreach:

```
foreach(var country in myCountryList)
{
    country.Name = "Foo";

    foreach(var province in country.Provinces)
    {
        province.Name = "Bar";

        foreach(var city in province.Cities)
        {
            city.Name = "Baz";
        }
    }
}
```

Two considerations:

- Avoiding nested foreaches is mostly an argument of **readability**, not one of performance. The `SelectMany` internally still iterates over all the collections anyway. This is unavoidable, since you can't access all the items in the collections without iterating over the collection.
- Methods that iterate over many levels of entities and set a lot of values suggest that you're violating SRP. This should likely be broken up into separate methods in order to remain SOLID-friendly.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Jumping on board of your example of City-Provinces-Countries, would you prefer a large collection of `City` with properties `Province` and `Country` or a smaller collection of `Country` containing a collection of `Province` containing a collection of `City`. Maybe the question is a bit too broad as it highly depends on how much calculations would be done on that one unique large collection though (also i'm assuming you will need to iterate through every single one of them).

Comment: @Calimero The issue is that if you start from Cities, you're going to end up doing double work. E.g. if both New York and Los Angeles are in the list, they are obviously part of the same country, do doing something like `currentCity.Province.Country` is going to alter the same country several times. Unless you specifically take the distinct countries, of course.

Comment: @Calimero: Also, I missed this part of your question: `prefer a large collection of City with properties Province and Country` It makes sense that cities are inside a province (or state, depending on which country we're talking about), rather than directly part of a country. Because (a) if you don't track that, you're missing key information of which city belongs to which province, or (b) cities are still part of provinces and `myCity.Country` is therefore redundant since it already can be accessed via `myCity.Province.Country` (there's no benefit to tracking country-city directly)